# How to handle joint between uneven ceiling drywall?

Tags: drywall, ceiling

After removing my cabinets for a kitchen remodel I realized that the previous owners installed a new drywall ceiling below the existing ceiling after installing the previous cabinets.

Now I have a 10ft wide 13 inch length gap that I am filling with drywall to "even"/"finish" the ceiling for the new cabinets.

I noticed that at the center about 5 feet point of the ceiling where the new drywall meets the old, the old drywall is sitting about half an inch lower than the rest of the ceiling for about 6-8 inches.  Will joint compound, mud and tape allow me to "hide" this dip?

85/ right above where the sink will be so no cabinets will cover it.! Dip starts towards the right side of the picture.  [drywall ceiling]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0HMn.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/2" of dip in a relatively small space can be sort of hidden with more mud, but I'd say it's always going to be noticeable.

2 alternatives. First, get some serious leverage underneath (something wide at the ceiling and an angled 2x4 from the floor) and see if you can push the offending drywall up. It may have just been poorly nailed in the past and is sagging.

If that doesn't do the trick, I'd even consider cutting back the offending piece and re-doing it. I get that almost nobody likes drywall work, but since you're doing some anyway, the incremental agony of a bit more will be modest.